# Somar valores ao total - SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho a seguinte `query`

```
SELECT 
    sum(tbl_purchase_product.sub_total) as sub_total 
FROM 
    (`tbl_purchase_product`) 
WHERE 
    `tbl_purchase_product`.`purchase_id` = '3'
```

Tenho um campo chamado `others_price`, e preciso somar ele ao sub_total, como eu conseguiria somar pela query?

Comment: `sum(tbl_purchase_product.sub_total) + sum(tbl_purchase_product.others_price) as sub_total`?

Comment: Não tenho certeza se funciona essa: `sum(tbl_purchase_product.sub_total + tbl_purchase_product.others_price) as sub_total` mas acredito que sim

Comment: Você precisa somar a cada linha, ou você precisa do valor total?

Comment: Só queria acrescentar + others_price, não quero somar tudo que tem no campo...

Comment: @Sr.AndréBaill, se alguma das respostas é a correta, marque-a como tal! [Porque é importante votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Para além disso dê um UP às respostas que lhe foram úteis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faça desta forma :

```
SELECT SUM(( sub_total ) + ( others_price )) 
FROM   (SELECT Count(tbl_purchase_product.sub_total) SUB_TOTAL, 
               Count(others_price)                   OTHERS_PRICE 
        FROM   tbl_purchase_product 
        WHERE  tbl_purchase_product `.` purchase_id ` = '3')
```

Answer (score 6):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_purchase_product.sub_total + tbl_purchase_product.others_price as sub_total 
FROM 
    (`tbl_purchase_product`) 
WHERE 
    `tbl_purchase_product`.`purchase_id` = '3'
```

Como você esta buscando pelo id acredito que você precisa de somar apenas deste registro, mas se você quiser somar de todos, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
    sum(tbl_purchase_product.sub_total + tbl_purchase_product.others_price) as sub_total 
FROM 
    (`tbl_purchase_product`) 
WHERE 
    `tbl_purchase_product`.`purchase_id` = '3'
```

## Alguns exemplo para poder indicar qual é o seu problema

Imagine o seguinte exemplo:

```
ID  VALUE1  VALUE2
===================
1   1       2
1   2       2
2   3       4
2   4       5
```

Se você fazer a seguinte query:

```
SELECT  ID, SUM(VALUE1), SUM(VALUE2)
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY ID
```

O resultado será:

```
ID, SUM(VALUE1), SUM(VALUE2)
1   3           4
2   7           9
```

Enquanto se você fazer desta forma:

```
SELECT  ID, VALUE1 + VALUE2
FROM    TableName
```

O resultado será:

```
ID, VALUE1 + VALUE2
1   3
1   4
2   7
2   9
```

E por outro lado fazendo desta maneira:

```
SELECT  ID, SUM(VALUE1 + VALUE2)
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY ID
```

O resultado:

```
ID, SUM(VALUE1 + VALUE2)
1   7
2   16
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877797/how-to-sum-two-fields-within-an-sql-query)

## Update

Resposta depois de esclarecimentos nos comentários

```
SELECT 
    sum(tbl_purchase_product.sub_total) + tbl_purchase_product.others_price as sub_total 
FROM 
    (`tbl_purchase_product`) 
WHERE 
    `tbl_purchase_product`.`purchase_id` = '3'
```

Comment: Neste caso, até daria certo... mas ele irá somar todos que tiverem o mesmo campo, eu preciso somar somente uma vez o campo..

Comment: sum(tbl_purchase_product.sub_total)  + tbl_purchase_product.others_price as sub_total 
talvez

Comment: O primeiro exemplo, ele somaria cada registro separadamente, mostrando a somatória de cada registro separadamente, enquanto que no segundo ele somaria cada registro e somaria tudo em um conjunto, o que você precisa?

Comment: Preciso somar uma vez só, não quero somar todos os registros, usei da forma que lhe passei agora e funcionou para o que eu preciso :)

Comment: Editei com o trecho que você colocou nos comentários

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que percebi quer somar o `others_price` **após** o somatório, por isso, experimente desta forma:

```
SELECT      TPP2.sub_total + TPP.others_price
FROM        tbl_purchase_product    TPP
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      SUM(sub_total) AS sub_total 
                FROM        tbl_purchase_product 
                GROUP BY    purchase_id
            )                       TPP2 ON TPP2.purchase_id = TPP.purchase_id
WHERE       TPP.purchase_id = '3'
```